# Second derivative of regular distribution of the absolute value

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta, weak-derivatives

Let $f:R\to R,x\mapsto|x|$ and $T_f\in\mathcal D'(R)$ the regular distribution of $f$. I want to calculate the second derivative of $T_f$. By definition:
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}T_f[\varphi]=T_f\left[\left(\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\right)^*\varphi\right]=T_f\left[\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\varphi\right]=\int_R|x|\frac{d^2}{dx^2}\varphi(x)dx,$$
because $\frac{d^2}{dx^2}$ is self-adjoint. As far as I know you can't simply swap the derivatives though, becuase $|x|\notin C^2(R)$.

Instead, I wanted integrate from $(-\infty,0)$ and $(0,\infty)$ (as $\{0\}$ is a null set of $R$):
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}T_f[\varphi]=-\int_{(-\infty,0)}\frac{d}{dx}|x|\frac{d}{dx}\varphi(x)dx-\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{d}{dx}|x|\frac{d}{dx}\varphi(x)dx$$
However, this should yield $0$:
$$\frac{d^2}{dx^2}T_f[\varphi]=\int_{(-\infty,0)}\frac{d}{dx}\varphi(x)dx-\int_{(0,\infty)}\frac{d}{dx}\varphi(x)dx=0,$$
as $\varphi$ is compactly supported.

However, if we visualize the distribution, one would expect to get the Heaviside step function $\theta$, whose distribution has the Dirac-Delta function $\delta_0$ as derivative.

Is my intuition or above calculation wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You fell at the last hurdle! Check the contribution of the endpoints of the integrals at 0.

Comment: You're right! I missed that. So the actual result should be $2\delta_0$, right?

Comment: @MetaColon Good, yes. The first derivative is not quite the Heaviside theta function, but $2\theta(x) - 1$. Hence the factor of two.